# Heroku Rails App will not launch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I deployed an app to Heroku successfully. I added some code for a contact form and now the app will not launch. Oddly enough, if I take out the contact form code it still doesn't launch. The Heroku log errors I'm getting are:

```
2016-02-05T02:02:11.535460+00:00 app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2016-02-05T02:02:11.535461+00:00 app[web.1]:     from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2016-02-05T02:02:12.518255+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-02-05T02:02:12.496744+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-02-05T02:02:14.019377+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=camdhall.herokuapp.com request_id=f0b71059-686b-46f4-9e69-2e62d55ca998 fwd="216.165.95.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

The rails console return this (I don't know why MailForm is uninitialized because it is correct in my contact controller):

```
/app/app/models/contact.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant MailForm (NameError)
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:472:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `block in eager_load!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `eager_load!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:142:in `require_application_and_environment!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:67:in `console'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /app/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /app/bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
```

And the message that I get when i run heroku open is:

```
GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
```

I have no earthly idea what is wrong. I tried reinstalling postgres, restarting the app, running rake db:migrate and checking the code for typos but I am at a lost. It runs on my local setup but not in production.

Comment: verify that mail_form gem is available for production in your Gemfile. Also, start the rails server in production mode locally to reproduce the issue locally

Comment: Wow... Thank you! I had it under my development group and never noticed! What a pain.